Should I run the KOreader AppImage as an executable or integrate it into my openSUSE Tumbleweed system?
I've downloaded the KOreader AppImage for my openSUSE Tumbleweed system, and I'm trying to decide whether I should run it directly as an executable or integrate it into my system by creating a desktop entry and icon.
Running it as an executable seems simpler - I can just execute ./KOreader-x.x.x-linux-xxx.AppImage from the terminal or double-click the AppImage file. However, this means I'll have to navigate to the AppImage's location every time I want to launch KOreader.
Integrating KOreader into my system would involve creating a .desktop file and placing the AppImage and icon in the appropriate directories. This would allow me to launch KOreader from my desktop's application menu or launcher, providing a more seamless experience.
My main priorities are:

Keeping things simple as a beginner Linux user
Having convenient access to launch KOreader regularly
Easily installing regular updates to KOreader

With the AppImage approach, I would need to manually download and replace the AppImage file whenever a new version is released. On the other hand, integration with the system might make it easier to update KOreader through the package manager (if an official package becomes available).
Which approach would you recommend for running the KOreader AppImage on openSUSE Tumbleweed - executing it directly or integrating it into the system? Are there any other factors I should consider when making this decision, particularly regarding regular updates?
If you've used AppImages on openSUSE before, I'd appreciate your insights and experiences. Thank you!
